# C linked list stack and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, reference, stack

I am new to C, and am trying to implement a stack with linked list. Currently set up the Stack, all good so far. The problem has come in when I try to push a new node onto the list.
 I currently have

In `main()`, `push()` is called by:

```
push(&(s.head), 'r');
```

The function `push` is:

```
void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, char value){
    printf("topPtr value %c", (*topPtr)->data); // - Is currently 'p'

    StackNodePtr sNP;
    sNP = malloc(Node_Size);
    sNP->data = value;                          // - Is currently 'r'
    sNP->nextPtr = *topPtr;

    printf("\nsNP value - %c", sNP->nextPtr->data);      // Prints p... cool
    topPtr = &sNP;      // Just assigned it???
    printf("\ntopPtr at end of push = %c", (*topPtr)->data);    // prints r... cool
    // WHY YOU NO REFERENCE sNP LATER!?!?
}
```

Meanwhile, back in main:

```
    printf("\non the stack...%c", stackTop(s.head));  // prints 'p'
```

It seems to work fine in push, however I call `printf()` on the node that `topPtr` pointed to and the value that `topPtr` used to be prints out instead (in this case 'p'). As far as I can tell from the hunting I've done, it looks and feels correct and I don't know what I have missed.

Could it be where I have done `topPtr = &sNP;`?

Any "push" in the right direction is a good push...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
topPtr = &sNP;      // Just assigned it???
```

No, you didn't. You assigned the value to local copy of pointer. You change the value of `topPtr` itself, and it is does not go outside. Instead, you should write to location it points to:

```
*topPtr = sNP;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
topPtr = &sNP;      // Just assigned it???
```

This assignment is not visible outside of the function.  `topPtr` is passed by value, i.e., a copy of it is made and passed to the function.  So, assigning a different value only modifies the copy; the original argument remains pointing to the old memory location.

If you need to modify the argument in that way you need another level of indirection, i.e., take a `StackNodePtr**`.

Also, I am assuming that `StackNodePtr` is a `typedef` for a `StackNode*`.  Am I right about that?  Is there a good reason to `typedef` this pointer type?  Typically it just serves to complicate things.  I would recommend `typedef`'ing a pointer type only when it is truly an opaque type (i.e., a `HANDLE` on Windows).

Comment: Yes you are right about the typedef, and thank you for explaining why it didn't work. I had a feeling it was something to do with visibility, but as to what the cause was, was unknown. As for why I am doing it this way, well it is just what has been requested of me, but now I should be able to deal with the rest of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
  *topPtr = sNP;
```

this way, the original head, the caller has passed the pointer to, that became the next of the new head, is "overwritten" correctly, and the caller has the correct pointer to the new head.

Comment: I am almost positive i tried that in the last few hours of playing with it, and that worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your function push is modifying the pointer topPtr. Since C is pass by value, the head is passed as a value and the copy passed gets modified in push. So, to modify the pointer itself,  you need to pass a pointer to pointer. Also, the function push() signature needs to be corrected to pass in a pointer to pointer. Finally, the topPtr assignment in push needs to be corrected as shown in the code snippet.

Do the following changes:

```
push(&(s.head), 'r'); // pass pointer to pointer, assuming head is pointer, it should be fine

void push(StackNodePtr **topPtr, char value){  // make first argument pointer to pointer. 

StackNodePtr sNP;
sNP = malloc(Node_Size);
sNP->data = value;                       
sNP->nextPtr = *topPtr; 

*topPtr = &sNP;     <------*topPtr needs to be assigned. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its looks like the bug is here:
topPtr = &sNP;      // Just assigned it???

instead of push returning void.
change it to return the new head of the stack.
return sNp;